# nginx permission denied while attempting to connect to upstream Ubuntu 14.04 Gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

Ok. I'm at the end of my rope here. I had this working, then I'm not sure if it was just coincidence but I set up VNC on the server and it stopped working (followed this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I've got a Django project through Digital Ocean. I followed their tutorial found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04

```
sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
015/05/04 22:03:33 [crit] 6399#0: *3 connect() to unix:/path/to/project.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: ipaddress, server: myproject.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/path/to/project.sock:/", host: "myproject.com"

ls -lh ~/myproject
srwxrwxrwx 1 myusername www-data    0 Apr  1 12:37 myproject.sock
```

I've been scouring all over but I can't find anything that quite matches what my problem seems to be, even though I have a feeling it's just a silly permission thing that got changed somehow.

If there's anything not clear enough above please ask me to elaborate.

Comment: My advice is to roll back the VNC and go with the less complex setup at first. But, if you want to keep VNC you may want to try this appraoch to implement: https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/wiki/Proxying-with-nginx

Comment: To be honest, I decided to just restart. The website was technically "live" but it was really just for me. So I didn't have much in the DB and it was all reproduce-able.

Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you made mistake with sock file in your nginx conf file:

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
```

As showed in error log nginx tries to open */path/to/project.sock* file. Change it to */home/username/myproject/myproject.sock*

Comment: Sorry. I left out some of that line for spacing reasons, but the error actually is pointing to: /home/myuser/myproject/myproject.sock

And my nginx config file looks just like that line.